# How to export DataTable on Primefaces with .txt format?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to export a datatable in .txt form with a vertical bar ("|") separator.

Is there any sample code that can be used for this case?
The showcase on primefaces is too complex and doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reuse csv exporter, and define attribute `options` of `p:dataExporter` with a new instance of `CSVOptions`. From there, you'll be able to define your own delimiter.

See a sample here https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/dataexporter?id=customization

If txt extension is that important to you, maybe you can try to inherit from `DataTableCSVExporter` and override `DataTableCSVExporter#getContentType` and `DataTableCSVExporter#getFileExtension` methods

See a sample here https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/dataexporter?id=custom-export

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried both, the custom delimiter works fine. But I still don't understand about `DataTableCSVExporter`, I can't found the getContentType and getFileExtension method.

Comment: They should be there, at least in 10.0.0

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm using pf 8.0, that's why it's not here. I've tried on pf 10.0 and it works perfectly! thank you!

Comment: Prefer using the last version of PrimeFaces, e.g 11.0.0 as of today ;)